# Using IP address vs host name in end-to-end request with SSL

Tags: security, ssl, end-to-end

So, note that this is not about browser-server communication. In server-to-server communication, would using the other server's IP address to make a request, as opposed to using its host name, reduce the likelyhood of MITM attack?

Comment: Well, at the very least, you're eliminating the possibility of DNS cache poisoning.

Comment: I'll keep this open for a while longer just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all Systems (including DNS) under your control, use the Domain Name. The risk for MITM attacks via DNS are as high as MITM via IP Spoofing. But you could move an application much better. You could just move the Domain Name.

If you have a valid, public signed SSL cert, you have the benefit that you don't need to buy a new one, if the IP changes.

If you don't have control over the other side, and worry about MITM: Don't connect to the system!

Comment: Properly authenticated SSL connections are immune to MiTM according to the experts. It doesn't matter if DNS is under the bad guy's control or not.

Comment: I have to connect to the other end because it's our payment gateway. :(

@GregS: I've heard about that, but I've also heard about various exploits like Thomas mentions.